# The OutputPath property is not set for the C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, project, csproj

I got this error message while debug/recompiling a C# Project:

> The OutputPath property is not set for project 'Example.csproj'.
> Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination
> of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Debug'
> Platform='x86'.  This error may also appear if some other project is
> trying to follow a project-to-project reference to this project, this
> project has been unloaded or is not included in the solution, and the
> referencing project does not build using the same or an equivalent
> Configuration or Platform.

I don't know what could be wrong in project configurations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectType>local</ProjectType>
    <ProjectVersion>7.10.377</ProjectVersion>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\</OutputPath>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{E34FF2B3-527D-4006-B312-3D88C491ADBC}</ProjectGuid>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <AssemblyName>Example</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>On</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Someone have an idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe I've missed the point here, but how is a C# project targeting a specific CPU platform? The usual target is "Any CPU," IIRC.

Comment: I tried change to AnyCPU instead of x86, but didn't works  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three methods you can try:

1. Please delete the bin and obj folders in the project root directory then rebuild the program.
2. Please place `OutputPath` before `<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />`. As follows:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build">
   <PropertyGroup> 
   ......
   </PropertyGroup>  
   <PropertyGroup> 
   ......
   </PropertyGroup>
   <PropertyGroup> 
   ...
   </PropertyGroup>                                       
   <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
   <ItemGroup>
   ......
   </ItemGroup>
   </Project>
   ```
3. Please check whether an uninstalled project is referenced. Deleting the offending reference can solve this problem.

Comment: I tried this three methods, and none worked for me. In the second, i got an error that the element <OuputPath> was not recognized before <Import Project>. But thank you for your help!

Comment: I compared a lot of .csproj files, and I found that the difference between yours is the location of <Import>. 
I mean to put <Import> after </PropertyGroup>.
I updated the second method, you could move <Import> to a suitable location according to the code.

Comment: If you have further problems, please feel free to contact me.

Comment: thanks for you attention again. I did this and now it's compiling, of course i received other errors, but this one it's solved!